# How to add time value to a new Row?

Tags: oracle10g

How can I add to a field in a Table built in Oracle database a time?

ex: I want to add the value `13:00:00` to the field `Time` in a table named `Data`

How can this be done?

I`m using Oracle 10g Express Edition

Comment: Hi sikas, you'll need to learn the difference between *storing* a date/time, and *displaying* a date/time. When you query a table with dates or timestamps, it converts the internal date/time values into a string format for display. If you don't explicitly specify the format using the `TO_CHAR` function, Oracle automatically picks the format based on the session's `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` setting.

Answer (score 0):

If this is one of the DATE field formats then for a record insert you would:

```
insert 
  into "DATA" ("TIME")
  values (to_date('13:00:00', 'HH24:MI:SS'));
```

You can verify this with:

```
select to_char("TIME", 'HH24:MI:SS')
from "DATA";
```

Comment: this is not I was asking ... I don`t know what changed the title of the question, I re-edited it. I want to add time value to new row for example, I want to add the clock (1 PM) in the format HH:MM:SS to a column in a new row.

Comment: What is the format of the "TIME" field? Can you do a "DESCRIBE <TABLENAME>" for me?

Comment: This is the SQL Command of my table:

CREATE table "Schedule" (
 "SID"  NVARCHAR2(9) NOT NULL,
 "Code"  NVARCHAR2(6) NOT NULL,
 "Room"  NVARCHAR2(4) NOT NULL,
 "Day"  NVARCHAR2(9) NOT NULL,
 "Time_From"  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
 "Time_To"  TIMESTAMP NOT NULL
)

Comment: insert into "DATA" ("TIME") values (to_date('13:00:00','HH24:MI:SS')); this didn`t work. when I select the data from the table DATA all what I see is this data 01-JUN-10

Comment: Because your nls_date_format is set to 'DD-MON-YY' by default. If you want to see a date field in a different format then you will need to "to_char" it to the format you want:

select to_char("time_from",'HH24:MI:SS') "time_from" from "Schedule";



Also, TIMESTAMP is actually DATE + TIME, not just time, so when you assign just a time the date will have been assumed to some extent. DATE field is actually probably sufficient enough for you as it is, since DATE keeps precision to the second, and TIMESTAMP I believe is precision to the microsecond or higher.